# Non-unit value on shape on a broadcastable dimension

Tags: numpy, theano

I am a theano newbie and I am implementing a simple perceptron based learning rule and I am getting following error, I fail to understand why am I getting this error?

Here my code:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
from theano import function
from theano import tensor as T
from theano import shared
from theano import Param
from theano.tensor.shared_randomstreams import RandomStreams
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
randGen = numpy.random

#perceptron

N = 400
feats = 2

randGen = np.random

data_class1 = randGen.normal(-3.0,1.0,N/2*feats).reshape(N/2,feats)
data_class0 = randGen.normal(3.0,1.0,N/2*feats).reshape(N/2,feats)

data_class1 = np.concatenate((np.ones((N/2,1)),data_class1) , axis=1)
data_class0 = np.concatenate((np.ones((N/2,1)),data_class0) , axis=1)

class1_label = np.ones(N/2)
class0_label = -1*np.ones(N/2)

D = (np.concatenate((data_class1,data_class0)), np.concatenate((class1_label,class0_label)))

training_steps = 10000

# Declare Theano symbolic variables
x = T.row("x")
y = T.row("y")
w = shared(randGen.normal(0.0,1.0,feats+1).reshape(feats+1,1), name="w")


x_data = T.matrix('x_data')
s_data = T.sgn(2*T.sgn(T.dot(x_data,w))-1)

predictedOut = function([x_data],s_data)

s = T.sgn(2*T.sgn(T.dot(x,w)-1))
prod = function([x],s)

z1 = T.row('z1')
w_up = function(inputs=[x,y,z1],outputs=[T.transpose(x)*(z1-y)])

z2 = T.row('z2')
train = function([z2],
                 updates=[(w,w-z2)]
                 )
count = 0
while np.abs(np.sum(predictedOut(D[0])-D[1])) > 0:
    print 'on example ',count
    a1 = D[0][count,:].reshape(1,feats+1)
    b1 = D[1][count].reshape(1,1)
    a2 = prod(a1).reshape(1,1)
    a3 = w_up(a1,b1,a2)[0].reshape(feats+1,1)
    train(a3)
    count += 1
```

ERROR:

```
on example 0 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/Users/theanoPractice/src/Perceptron.py", line 68, in <module> 
train(a3) 
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 497, in __call__ 
allow_downcast=s.allow_downcast) 
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/type.py", line 174, in filter 
" dimension.", data.shape, self.broadcastable) 
TypeError: ('Bad input argument to theano function at index 0(0-based)', 'Non-unit value on shape on a broadcastable dimension.', (3, 1), (True, False))
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it runs through fine. This doesn't mean that it works on my machine though: The loop is never run because the condition evaluates to `False`. If I have some time later I'll check what happens if I force the function call.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is happening here, because I am not completely understanding your architecture (in particular your function `train` seems strange alone and only works when called on the output of `w_up`). But I have the feeling that this may be due to the fact that you are using `T.row` a lot, which has the characteristics `(ndim=2, broadcastable=[True,False])`. You then proceed to transpose them and that may cause the problem (although it shouldn't - `.broadcastable` gets tranposed accordingly, but maybe it is still getting muddle). Why don't you just work with `T.fvector` instead?

Comment: Thanks!! So I found the problem and the answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the problem in my code,

The "train" function expects a row, but the value being passed is a (3, 1) column vector.

So here is the corrected version:

```
train = function([z2],
                 updates=[(w,w-T.transpose(z2))]
                 )
count = 0
while np.abs(np.sum(predictedOut(D[0])-D[1])) > 0 and count < 1000 :
    print 'on example ',count
    a1 = D[0][count%N,:].reshape(1,feats+1)
    b1 = D[1][count%N].reshape(1,1)
    a2 = prod(a1).reshape(1,1)
    a3 = w_up(a1,b1,a2)[0].reshape(1,feats+1)
    train(a3)
    count += 1
```